# How do I add event listeners to check the number of checkboxes selected on a page and display an alert?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

So I have a web page that contains a list of 20 checkboxes. If the user ticks any 5 of them, I want to give an alert saying that they have made the maximum number of choices.

let checked=document.getElementsByClassName("chkbox"); //classname added to each checkbox in html

checked.addEventListener('change', () =>
{

```
  let counter=0;
    for(let i=0;i<checked.length;i++){ //to update counter each time a checkbox gets changed
        if(checked[i].checked){
        counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter==5){
            alert("You have made maximum choices. Proceed to next form")
        }
```

})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by checking number of ticked boxes whenever a user clicks on the box.

You can read the comments in the code to better understand it

```js
// Defind how many check boxes a user can check
// You requested 5 but to make it less html code, I put 2 in the variable below
var checkboxLimit = 2;

// Get every check box by using querySelectorAll
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(
// For each check box add on click event listener
  input => input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // get number of check boxes by passing :check attribute to the query selector
    var numberTickedBoxes = 
      document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    
    // check if the number of ticked boxes are more than allowed limit
    if(checkboxLimit < numberTickedBoxes){
      alert("You are allowed to check " + checkboxLimit + " boxes")
    }
  })
);
```

```html
<label>1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />
<br/>
<label>2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />
<br/>
<label>3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />
<br/>
```

Same as above but after the user checks the limited amount, no more checkbox get checked by using `event.preventDefault();` in the if statement

```js
var checkboxLimit = 2;

document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(
  input => input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var numberTickedBoxes = 
      document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    
    if(checkboxLimit < numberTickedBoxes){
      alert("You are allowed to check " + checkboxLimit + " boxes");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
);
```

```html
<label>1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />
<br/>
<label>2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />
<br/>
<label>3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />
<br/>
```

As Cat mentioned in the comments below you can also have a single event listener for all the checkboxes

```js
var checkboxLimit = 2;

// get the container for the checkboxes and add click event listener 
document.querySelector("#checkboxes")
  .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // the element where the click happened? inside the checkboxes div
    let target = event.target; 
    
    // if the targeted element is HTML input element 
    if (target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      // if the input type is checkbox
      if(target.type == "checkbox"){
        var numberTickedBoxes = 
          document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
      
        if(checkboxLimit < numberTickedBoxes){
          alert("You are allowed to check " + checkboxLimit + " boxes");
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
<label>1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />
<br/>
<label>2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />
<br/>
<label>3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be even better if it employed [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to allow having just a single listener.

Comment: @Cat you are right. I will modify the code to include this example as well

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the "disabled" attribute of checkboxes rather than alerting the user so he won't be able to check any other boxes.
You still have to have a check counter in your JS to know when to activate the disabled attribute of your inputs.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, but it's valid feedback for OP. A working demo in a snippet an an explanation of what makes it a better design would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First you fetch the checkboxes. Then you can iterate over the HTMLCollection. Inside the loop you check if the property checked is set. If yes increase the counter by one.

```js
const fs = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')
var cb = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=favorite_pet]");
const limit = 2;
let counter = 0;


for (let i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {  
  cb[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter--;
      console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
    }
    if (counter >= 2) {
      alert('warning')
    }
    console.log(counter)
  });    
}
```

```html
<fieldset>      
    <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Cats" >Cats<br>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Dogs">Dogs<br>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="Birds" >Birds<br>      
    <br>      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />      
</fieldset>
```